# Jagged Polygon Edge Generalization in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, generalization

I have a polygon which the edge is quite normal when zoomed out:
[image]

But when zoomed in this is how the edge looks like (jagged) because it was converted pixel by pixel from a raster, is there a generalization tool that can make it less jagged?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

Comment: If you need a QGIS solution too then please ask that as a separate question and let us know what you have tried within that software.

Comment: If you created this dataset using the raster to polygon tool simply tick on the simplify option that will smooth the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS you can try tool [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm):

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

[image]

Before running the tool backup your data:

> Caution: This tool modifies the input data. See Tools with no outputs
>   for more information and strategies to avoid undesired data changes.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Any chance that there is similar tool in QGIS?

Comment: @chenghopan If you need to know about QGIS too then please ask a new question.